# jquery .validate error in jslint

Tags: jquery, debugging

Need help, not sure if this is critical but want to get it right. I have the following addMethod, and I get the following error when running through jslint: 
    "Problem at line 818 character 28: Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'.
    } else return true;"

Here's the function:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
            "InsideCanada",
            function(value, element) {
                var selectedCountry = $("#Country").val();
                if ($("#CNC1N").is(":checked") && (selectedCountry!=="CAN")) {
                    return false;
                } else return true;
            },
            "Cannnot select Toronto Stock Exch - In Canada."
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

Add some brackets: `else { return true; }`

Comment: at the risk of being annoying anything wrong with this array? var NorthAmerica = new Array["USA","CAN","MEX"];

Comment: @Dirty Bird yes that's a syntax error actually. Don't use "new Array()"; just say `var NorthAmerica = ['USA', 'CAN', 'MEX'];`

Comment: @Dirty, don't worry, you're not being annoying :-) Arrays can be declared in two ways, either `... = new Array("USA", "CAN", "MEX")` or `... = ["USA", "CAN", "MEX"]` as [described here](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_obj_array.asp), so yes, there *is* something wrong with it ;-)

Comment: when I go with "else { return true; } it will trigger the error, but when you correct it it doesn't remove the error class. Interesting. thx for the tip on the array @Pointy @Klaus

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
return !($("#CNC1N").is(":checked") && selectedCountry!=="CAN");
```

?

Comment: Ill give it a shot. Don't really understand these addMethods too well, got them working and left them alone.